# External JDBC user store for WSO2 Identity Server v3.2.3

Tags: jdbc, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to add an external JDBC user store to WSO2 Identity Server v3.2.3
WSO2 documentation (http://docs.wso2.org/display/identity/Configuring+an+External+JDBC+User+Store) does not specify how this is done for a custom user schema. An older version of Identity Server supported "Add External User Storage" (or similar) in the management console where one could specify SQL statements for user data queries. However, v3.2.3 does not have this in the UI anymore.

So, is a custom user schema possible or does Identity Server require a fixed user schema?

BR,
Harri

Answer (score 0):

In case your custom schema vastly differs from what we have by default (please see the commented out section in user-mgt.xml) then you need to extend JDBCUserStoreManager and override some of it methods to cater your requirements.